# Motion Tracked camera is far away from the origin after applying the origin / floor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, motion-capture

When I try to use Motion Tracking, the camera is very far away from the origin of the coordinate system. It's not exactly an ideal setting for motion tracking.
[image]

The tracker circled in green is the origin of the coordinate system, and the tracker circled in blue is the Y-axis setter. Is there a way that the camera can be brought closer to the center of the global coordinate system?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Is there a way that the camera can be brought closer to the center?". Do you want to zoom in on specific parts of the footage or is the issue with where how the 3D plane is placed in the scene?

Comment: I selected the camera, and its credentials are (60m, -46m, 35m [x,y,z]). The center in a Blender project is (0m,0m,0m). If that makes sense, I don't want the camera to be that far away. That's what I mean by bringing the camera closer to the center.

Comment: I see, yes that makes sense.

Comment: At bottom part of "Orientation" panel (Set Origin etc.) you have "Scale" and "Distance" options ... there you should set what you need.

Comment: Those two were useful with the distance. Thank you very much!